# ThemeOverlay not showing changes in the preview/design view in Android Studio after update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I just recently updated my Android Studio and ever since doing that the ThemeOverlay property is not showing on my buttons in the preview/design editor which it did prior to the update. However when I run the App on the Device the ThemeOverlay works. Below is some test code for the button. I have set the background attribute of the Button to Blue and the text of the button to Test Me

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Me"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The theme attribute is set to TheOverLay.AppCompat.Dark so that the text on the button is light but it's not showing in the design editor/preview in Android Studio. The text still shows as dark/Black. When I run this on a connected device it works fine.
Is this because of something that has changed with the current update?

Comment: My guess is that the design preview and live device are using different API levels. Design preview will use whatever your target API level is. The live device uses whatever is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this inside your base theme:
`<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/some_color</item>` which is global basically, all the buttons will have the color you defined inside your theme file.

On the other hand, I believe you cannot get the button theme from ThemeOverlay. Instead, create a new style and set the parent to `Button`.

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/Red</item>
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/Red</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

And you can apply the style as:
`android:theme="@style/CustomButton"`

Comment: With a ThemeOverlay, `colorPrimary` is used to color buttons.